# Duplicate class in Kotlin Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependencies

[image: Image Example]

I kept on getting an error that there is a duplicate error in classes.
[This is what I have under org.jetbrains.kotlin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92lfH.png)
[.idea/libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0zHs.png)

It seems like the problem is because there is two different dependencies for Kotlin, from *stdlib* and *stdlibjdk8*, but I don't know how to remove either one from my module/project dependencies. How can I do it?

Here's the full error code:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
```

I've tried deleting the files from the org.jetbrains.kotlin, but whenever I build the app in Android Studio, the files will be redownloaded again.

This is my module app [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) code:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.umfs"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    namespace 'com.example.umfs'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    implementation 'com.github.marlonlom:timeago:4.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I thought I was the only one who got this error while having had no use of Kotlin anywhere in my large project.. Then I came across this very-obvious-to-me-now answer and it solved it very simply for me...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75315276/4355877

Comment: @Mick Thank you so much for the tip, a lifesaver for those shunning Kotlin.

Comment: @midnighthowlers Try this solution once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75974885/16765223

Comment: This answer worked for me. It's on page 2, that's why I'm adding this as a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75550269/4833705

Comment: Why do we need 62 answers to this question?

Answer (score 307):

Simply. For me, just change this Gradle plugin from 1.7.10 to 1.8.0 Then synchronise → invalidate caches → build

From:

```
plugins {
    ....
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

To:

```
plugins {
    ....
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: Note: After updating to '1.8.0', do not forget to update kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion as '1.4.0' .

Comment: I get a compilation error: 
**This version (1.3.2) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.7.20 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.8.0 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).**

Comment: Question as a noob: Where should I add the above?

Comment: If you are using ksp, do not forget to update it too. https://github.com/google/ksp/releases. For kotlin version 1.8.0 ksp must be 1.8.0

Comment: got this error:The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

Comment: @PrasannjeetSingh It is `build.gradle` file

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - You can update the kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion to 1.4.4 in app level build.gradle. You can find this in ComposeOptions {} block. Check the link below to find the correctly mapped version (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Comment: This is useful but you also need edit kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion= "1.4.3".  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin?hl=zh-cn

Comment: I had the same issue. By default Android Studio creates a project with `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'` (**Compose Compiler Version**) and `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false` (**Kotlin Version**). And the problem comes when you try to use/update library versions: For example `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'` to 1.10.1 , result in that error(you'll have to look for the right version). **To avoid this use the latest version of Compose Compiler Version and Kotlin version** (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Comment: I replaced: 
- apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

with :

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}

And it works.

Comment: When updating `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` to `1.8.0` add `android`>`composeOptions` > `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.0"` in your app level `build.gradle` file

Comment: from me fix by change:
from:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    ...
}

to:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    ...
}

fix that issue

Answer (score 223):

*See [this note](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#obligatory-check-for-jvm-targets-of-related-kotlin-and-java-compile-tasks) in the official Kotlin documentation for an explanation of how alignment works with these dependencies and build flags. The below original answer is an alternative approach which doesn't take this into account.*

This is because `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` are older dependencies that should be replaced by `kotlin-stdlib` (As @MrPNG pointed out from [the what's new docs for Kotlin 1.8](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#updated-jvm-compilation-target)). However, other libraries may still declare a dependency on them, which needs to be replaced with a dependency on `kotlin-stdlib`.

You can override how the jdk7 and jdk8 versions are resolved like this (in your `app/build.gradle`):

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
}
```

The `constraints` section above can be added in alongside your other dependencies. Choose the version (here `1.8.0`) to match the one you actually want to be used, which should be the one that your non-jdkN-named version is in the duplicate class error (e.g., `(org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0)`)

If you have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` in this file, then it doesn't need to separately also say to depend on the stdlib in dependencies, so remove any lines that look like this:

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

(thanks to [this blog](https://dev.to/retyui/fix-react-native-android-builds-duplicate-class-kotlincollections-found-in-modules-jetified-kotlin-stdlib-180-2ca7))

Comment: I have a project where the build failed for the same reason as above.  And I am not using any kotlin code in my project.  Is there a way to disable any and all kotlin dependencies so that I can't possibly get a "duplicate classes" for kotlin dependencies?

Comment: If you're not using any kotlin code, it sounds like a very different problem even if it has the same error message... probably worth posting as a separate question

Comment: @AJW You may think that you don't use any Kotlin code in your project, but the dependencies you use can use Kotlin code inside them (for example various AndroidX libraries are written in Kotlin).

Comment: It works now. You can also find information in [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54136/Duplicated-classes-cause-build-failure-if-a-dependency-to-kotlin-stdlib-specified-in-an-android-project).

Comment: With Android Studio Giraffe (2022.3.1 Beta 1), I get a warning in the IDE: `'implementation' is defined by 'dependencies' but used within 'constraints'`. Any idea why, and how to get rid of it?

Comment: This solution worked for me but I also tried out a much cleaner approach from the official kotlin docs. Here is the link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#usage-of-the-latest-kotlin-stdlib-version-in-transitive-dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Wish `gradle` can't be little smart to detect and fix this type of issues.

Comment: I've updated my build.gradle with this & it still does not work.

Comment: For more recent versions of kotlin, this solution should not be needed...; using the `kotlin-stdlib` declaration instead is probably what you need to do (as hinted at in the first two paragraphs)... but if you find another scenario you could share the details?

Answer (score 157):

I have tried all the previous solutions but after adding the below code it was working.

```
dependencies {
   ... ... ...
   implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
   ... ... ...
}
```

Comment: This worked for me even though our project is a pure Java project without any Kotlin code. The clue that it would came from here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55297/kotlin-stdlib-should-declare-constraints-on-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-and-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7

Comment: This fixed my issue as well

Comment: This also worked for me. I think this is sufficient if you are not using Kotlin directly.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well: project is pure Java (no Kotlin).

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer (y)

Comment: Hello!

This worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 59):

I was getting the same error after upgrading the Android annotation library from version 1.4.0 to 1.6.0,

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
```

So I downgraded to 1.5.0 and the error was gone:

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
```

Comment: I'm not using kotlin in a project and this solved my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately Kotlin is now a dependency for many of the Android core libraries, so now you are using Kotlin indirectly whether you want it or not.  Unfortunately, that means we get the build problems that come with it.

Answer (score 40):

Upgrade kotlin android plugin and kotlin compiler

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10'
}
android {
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Although I only needed to upgrade the kotlin android plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Adding the plugin worked for me, although my project is only Java and I don't use Kotlin at all. This really looks to me like a flaw in Android Studio, if not completely a bug.

Comment: same here; adding "implementation (platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))" fixed the issue, EVEN if I have no kotlin code.

Answer (score 31):

You can now update the lifecycle dependencies to the most up-to-date versions, and simply add the following line in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    (...)

    // Fix Duplicate class
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

}
```

Comment: Everything complied fine. Then I updated androidx fragments from 1.5.7 to 1.6 and about 100 kotlin duplicate class errors occurred. What worries me is that they did not vanish when I got back to 1.5.7 and deleted build and invalidate cache.
Its like black magic - it messes you up and sticks with you even if you revert back to older version!
Still this implementation fixes those duplicate classes thank you

Comment: Can anyone please elaborate on why this works? I have no clue how it fixed my issue of duplicate classes.

Comment: the only fix that worked for me is this, thanks!

Comment: @WahajMubeen apparently we are using mutliple dependencies in pubsec.yaml file, and they all need the kotlin versions to be aligned, but each uses a diff version, which causes this issue, the fix mentioned above , is a solution to fix the duplicate class error. It resolves the conflict by using the Kotlin Bill of Materials (BOM) to ensure that all Kotlin dependencies in your project use the same version.

Answer (score 28):

I tried many ways to solve this same prolem but didnt work
I tried to add this dependencies below in my "**build.gradle(module:app)**"..

```
implementation (platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```

and then synce now, it will resolve this error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved the day. I recommend everyone to try this first.

Answer (score 23):

I solved the problem by changing the Kotlin class path dependency in the root *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file from

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20-RC"
```

to

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
```

Answer (score 14):

edit app/build.gradle file in flutter

```
dependencies {

    (...)

    // Fix Duplicate class
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

}
```

Answer (score 13):

I was using `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10` before in our SDK and then I updated kotlin to v1.8.0 and that's when I started getting the above error in our Android Java front end application.
Using `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom` resolved the issue with transitive dependencies and might be a cleaner approach since it doesn't leak Kotlin details into the Java application.

so I just replaced

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10"
```

with below which solved the problem for me.

```
// Align versions of all Kotlin components
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0"
```

Answer (score 13):

Add the below line in your **build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
dependencies {

(...)

// Fix Duplicate class
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

}
```

This is because **kotlin-stdlib-jdk7** and **kotlin-stdlib-jdk8** are older dependencies that should be replaced by *kotlin-stdlib*. However, other libraries may still declare a dependency on them, which needs to be replaced with a dependency on *kotlin-stdlib*.

Answer (score 12):

This problem will be solved by adding the dependency in build.gradle(app) file

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0"
```

it's working properly

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34728815)

Comment: For me, this line works as expected, 
in dependencies from the build.gradle (Module: app) add:  
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

I find here: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2018

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Compose you need to update the Compose Compiler (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler) to 1.4.2 and Kotlin to 1.8.10 at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Add this

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    }
```

Step 2: Add this on the dependencies

```
dependencies {

.....

  constraints{
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.10'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.10'
    }
}
```

***Note***: version '1.8.10', jdk7:1.8.10 and jdk8:1.8.10 are the same...

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.10'
    }
}
```

Adding this to the end of the Gradle file helps.

Comment: This solution literally fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it. For me it was important to know that it needs to go into the android/app/build.gradle file, and not in the android/build.gradle file.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error on my Kotlin project. When I add Ktor to my project and upgraded the library versions, and then I got the wired long error. This is how I fixed it.

I used compose version 1.4.0

```
ext {
    compose_ui_version = '1.4.0'
}
```

kotlin version `1.8.0`, the latest one `1.8.10` not compatible with compose `1.4.0` So I used,

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
```

Then, adjust the `composeOptions` on app level build.gradle file, like

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
}
```

These are the three changes that I have done and I got escaped from the wired error. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 6):

```
lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.6.1
```

down

```
lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.5.1
```

I managed to get it working by lowering the dependency values.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by making Compose Compiler and JetBrains Kotlin plugins compatible

First, make sure are you using **org.jetbrains.kotlin.android** plugin version above 1.8.0.

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
plugins {
  ...
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.21' apply false
}
```

Then check compatible version of Compose Compiler from below link and update **build.gradle(app)**:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#pre-release_kotlin_compatibility

```
android {
  ...
  composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.7'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Workaround for earlier KGP versions now is:

#### File *app/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

add this inside your **dependencies**, it will solve the **error**.

```
dependencies {

    (...)

    // Fix Duplicate class
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

}
```

Comment: Great! Using the Kotlin Bill of Materials (BOM) is indeed a good approach to manage the Kotlin version and ensure consistency throughout your project. By specifying the Kotlin BOM, you're effectively managing the Kotlin version for your project and avoiding conflicts related to duplicate class issues.

Including the Kotlin BOM allows you to define the Kotlin version in a single place, making it easier to manage dependencies and prevent version conflicts. It's a good practice, especially when dealing with Kotlin in multi-module or complex projects.

Comment: Working through this one now. I added this and got past the duplicate class error but now run into:

```
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the release notes of Kotlin 1.8.0 (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#updated-jvm-compilation-target), you shouldn't specify `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` nor `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` as dependencies anymore and, instead, just use `kotlin-stdlib`.

Answer (score 4):

It is maybe some updated version dependency. In my new compose app, when I updated

> implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:*'(new version)
> from 1.0.0-alpha11

I will got this error. Try revert updated dependency.

Also, I was getting this error when `android studio` was added in my Gradle modules `ktx:+` dependency.

Comment: Same here. Had to downgrade material3 version to ```'1.1.0-alpha04'```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today and I fixed it by upgrading both `Kotlin` `std-lib` for android and the `std-lib` itself.
Also it's worth mentioning that if you're using compose, you have upgrade the  `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion`

Here is the final setup

- gradle file at Module level

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
}
```

- root project gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when upgrading one of these

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
```

To version 2.6.0. When rolling back to 2.5.3 the error went away.

Comment: I had the same issue. Downgraded from `2.7.2` to `2.5.3` and it worked. But why is the new version not working? I don't know...

Answer (score 4):

If I update kotlin version to 1.8.0 then it forces me to use **view binding**

i.e. `classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10'`

then if you want to keep kotlin version as it was before then just add it in app level gradle-

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0"
```

it will solve *duplicate class* issues though it is a temporary solution.
Here my AGP version is **7.4.1** and Gradle version is **7.5**

Answer (score 4):

The issue may be easely fixed by one line only:

```
dependencies {
.....
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same errors in my project. What finally helped me was the following steps

1-I have updated the buildScript: as below

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'
    }
}
then change pluggin 
From

plugins {
....
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false

}

To

plugins {
....
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

lastly updated in build.grade(app)

Change in android scope {}

```
    android {
    ......
    composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
        }
    .......
    }
```

To the following and the errors were gone

```
 composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }

Hope it helps someone else
```

Answer (score 3):

kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion(compose) -> kotlin_version

1.4.4 -> 1.8.10

1.4.3 -> 1.8.10

1.4.2 -> 1.8.10

1.4.1 -> 1.8.0

1.4.0 -> 1.8.0

1.4.0-alpha02 -> 1.7.21

1.4.0-alpha01 -> 1.7.20

1.3.2 ->1.7.20

...

Other versions: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting similar error. These settings worked for me.

Note: I'm using `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1`

`build.gradle(:project)` settings

Old use:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
...
```

New use:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.8.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
...
```

`build.gradle(:app)` settings

Old use:

```
...
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
...
```

New use:

```
...
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
...
```

Gradle Projects Settings

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding this code inside app level/build.gradle

```
dependencies{
 ....
    constraints{
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.10'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.10'
    }
}
```

and adding this code inside project level/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    .....
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
}
```

It fixed this error 100%. It worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome Faiz

Comment: BUY ME COFFEE : https://www.buymeacoffee.com/stephenmui8

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after updating my Android Studio. For this to work, I had to downgrade my dependencies like this

Previous use:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'
}
```

Changing to:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2023

Recently, I had the same issue where most of the duplicate classes belonged to Kotlin. One of the errors was something like this:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
```

I had this issue because I was using a buggy kotlin version. Upgrade your kotlin version to `1.8.0-Beta`. Follow this:

in your `android/build.gradle`, first add this in the `ext` section:

```
kotlinVersion = "1.8.0-Beta"
```

Now, go down to the dependencies section and add this:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
```

Finally, make sure your `JAVA_HOME` points to a JDK11.

Doing these fixed my problem. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade these deps to

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
```

Comment: it just can be a temporary solution, but it helped me a lot !

Answer (score 2):

As I checked all ways, if there is a alpha version like this :

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0-alpha02'
```

**change it to**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
```

then **Add** class path in `build.gradle()`

```
 dependencies {
     
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of a Compose compiler version and Kotlin version incompatibility. when I posting this answer, most updated compatible versions were:

- Compose compiler version: 1.4.6
- Kotlin Version: 1.8.20

You can always find most updated compatible versions on this page: *[Compose to Kotlin Compatibility Map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)*

You can set this versions in app-level Gradle file like this:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
}
```

and

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issue after accepting Android Studio's suggestion to update certain dependencies.

I looked at all the solutions here but none applied in my case because... I am **not using kotlin** in my code anywhere (i.e. my development is all in pure Java).

That led me to finding the following line in `build.gradle`:

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
```

I just deleted it and **all built perfectly** as before the updates.

I have no idea why my `build.gradle` had a reference to `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0` in the first place (before the upgrade).

Comment: Thank you so much, I had same problem with pure java, but because I updated `androidx.core:core` to 1.10.1 while keeping `fresco*` at 2.6.0. I had to revert `androidx.core:core` to 1.9.0 because I cannot use newer `fresco*` 3.0.0.

Comment: @ZaFaR97 You are very welcome. What baffles me is that at some point I thought `androidx.core:core` was needed but now I see that it is not needed. I must have gone through some transitional stage, because my project was so old, that it had to undergo a lot of changes.

Comment: I didn't know if it is needed in my project, I leave it till I can test it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dependencies {
     configurations.implementation {
         exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
     }
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change **ext.kotlin_version** in **android\build.gradle** to **1.8.0**

```
buildscript {
//ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For compose, use stable-version of material3:

`androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1`

And then:

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false`

Answer (score 1):

I noted the issue specifically after upgrading to these 2 libraries:

- **`Material3`** version **`1.1.0-alpha05`**
- **`Runtime-livedata`** version **`1.4.0-beta01`**

This is are full dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

This is the error I was getting with **`Jdk-18.0.2`**

> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in
> modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0)
> and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20

The way around it for the time being is to downgrade these 2 libraries until the bug is corrected or updates are made.

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.0-alpha01'
```

Mind you there may be other dependencies that are affected and if you have recently upgraded the dependencies, you may need to rollback the updates and eliminate the library one by one to identify the troublesome one.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer worked for me, but the Kotlin DSL syntax is:

```
kotlin("android").version("1.8.10").apply(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I first tried David Fraser's solution (constraints {...}) and it worked fine, but I found it strange and discarded it.
Instead I changed the plugins as follows:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.8.0' apply false // before 1.7.10
```

This also fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Such problem occurred after upgrading jetpack compose from `1.3.0` to `1.4.0`.

If you find this problem, please refer to the [Kotlin Compose compatibility map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) in order to find **matching Kotlin/Compose Compiler** versions.

When you have found them, you need to make sure that:

- Gradle plugin has the right version (in `buildSrc`: `build.gradle.kts` for KTX gradle or in regular Gradle the root `build.gradle` one: `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:<KOTLIN_VERSION>")`)
- Kotlin dependency has right version (if you use multi-module app and use Kotlin directly (`implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:<KOTLIN_VERSION>")`)
- `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = <COMPOSE_VERSION>` is matching

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac.  I hadn't worked on my app in a while 6-12 months maybe.  I was just checking in to make sure that Android Studio and the dependencies weren't too out of date.  I received the same error as noted in the question.

1. When I tried to change my `ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.20"` to 1.8.x, I received a warning about `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` being inconsistent with my Kotlin version.
2. When I went into `Tools`->`Kotlin`->`Configure Kotlin Updates` and noticed that I couldn't get the the recent 1.8.20 version.

[image: Tool Menu]
[image: Kotlin Config Window]

3. Then went to see if I needed an `Android Studio`->`Check for updates...`
   [image]
4. I in fact did need a major release update arctic fox to flamingo.
   After upgrading to Flamingo, I was able to update both locations of Kotlin Version to 1.8.20.  `Tools`->`Kotlin`->`Configure Kotlin Updates` and `ext.kotlin_version = "1.8.20"`
5. Did `File`->`Invalidate Cache` and reboot
6. Did `Build`->`Clean Project`
7. I updated whatever else needed to be updated with Flamingo
8. Built and ran -> and ...
   `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 6s`
   `38 actionable tasks: 38 executed`

Answer (score 1):

(gradle.properties)

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

and app (build.gradle)

```
constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, only changing the implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1' to   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0' worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem and added this line in the build.gradle:

```
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the real solution, put this code in your gradle (app)

```
 constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while it was working two days ago...

I changed to

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
}
```

and
`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false`
in build.gradle (Project).

Then clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my project but mine was caused by different jetpack compose libraries having different versions and I put the specific version number `"1.3.3"` which caused other libraries that have later version numbers to not be found. I fix this by using compose BOM which provides the latest version to each library

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0-alpha06")
```

With

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0-alpha04")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20"`

With

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10"`

And then If you used `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin, then remove this line. And use `View binding` to whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate id detected is because there is a duplicate id you defined. For example, you defined the id in project level build.gradle file and if you define the same id in your module-level build.gradle file then it is simply a duplicate id problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading to 1.8.0
then you should add

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

By [@ArdaKazancı answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76054519/6576302), I did a similar change: (agp:7.4.2, gradle: 7.5)

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This duplication happens because some of the libraries still use module `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` or `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` instead of the new module `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib`, therefore the class duplication accure.

To fix this we need to replace this module by ourselves:

```
modules {
        module('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8')
                { replacedBy 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib', 'kotlin fixes' }
        module('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7')
                { replacedBy 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib', 'kotlin fixes' }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all lines in file *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* to:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

I'd say downgrade the dependencies. I just do it and it works very well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a pure Java app.

If you want to update :

- androidx.appcompat:appcompat from 1.4.x to 1.5.0
- androidx.annotation:annotation from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0

And probably a few other.

It seems you need to add something like this in your project.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in the project-level [build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) file.

```
plugins {

    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in `~\android\app\build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
```

to:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this line **works as expected**, in *dependencies* from the *build.gradle* (Module: app) add:

```
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```

I found the right answer here: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2018