# A failure occurred while executing app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following configuration:

Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

dependencies.gradle:

```
ext.versions = [
    minSdkLib        : 23,
    compileSdk       : 33,
    versionCode      : 6,
    versionName      : '1.0.6',

    kotlin_version : '1.7.21',
    hilt_android : '2.40.1',
    hilt_compiler : '2.40.1',
]
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    apply from: './dependencies.gradle'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$versions.hilt_android"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'

    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

apply from: '../dependencies.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        // for view binding:
        viewBinding true
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****"
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName: "****"]
        minSdkVersion versions.minSdkLib
        targetSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
        versionCode versions.versionCode
        //versionCode buildDateTime
        versionName versions.versionName
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "****")
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        "****"
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1"
    /*work */
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    // Added Dependencies
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    //
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1'

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.2.0")
    /*Marshmallow permission*/
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    /*This is a logger with a small, extensible API which provides utility on top of Android's normal Log class.*/
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.13.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0'
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    //Dagger Hilt
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$versions.hilt_android"
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:76.3809.111'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$versions.hilt_compiler"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

    // Paging
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.1"

    /*kotlin coroutines*/
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.1.0"
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.2")
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'


    /*ssp for text size for all multiple devices*/
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    /*sdp for all multiple devices size*/
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    /*Image picker and Camera*/
    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'

    //Biometric
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'

    //FCM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'

    //Calendar
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.8.0-rc01'

    //Horizontal Calendar
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4'

    //Stripe SDK
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.16.1'

    //Testing Libs
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0"
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.4'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    ///Zoom image
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.3.1'
    ///S: glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    //Bar
    implementation 'com.github.hadiidbouk:ChartProgressBar-Android:2.0.6'
     // One Signal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
    // Color picker
    implementation 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.1'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava2', version: '2.6.1'
    // Toast
    implementation 'com.github.ahmmedrejowan.CuteToast:CuteToast:1.2'
}
```

I have the following errors:

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)

Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
```

I don't understand why it tries to get the classes compiled with Kotlin 1.8.0. I don't have anywhere in the project used this version of Kotlin. I tried multiple version of gradle. I updated the Android Studio and some of the libraries.
I am stuck with this problem for 2 days. Please help! I can share more info about the project if needed.
Many thanks!

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55297/kotlin-stdlib-should-declare-constraints-on-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-and-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7

Comment: @Lino could you please give more details about the link you proposed?

Comment: the idea was to apply the workaround described in the link, in particular the dependency constraint: `dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation(project(":kotlin-sdklib-jdk7"))
        implementation(project(":kotlin-sdklib-jdk8"))
    }
}`

Comment: @Lino I added the constraints block in the build.gradle (app) dependencies block and i get this error: "A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Project with path ':kotlin-sdklib-jdk7' could not be found in project ':app'."

Comment: @ValentinCerneanu i ran into the same issue, the only thing I found that fixed it for me is adding this to app/build.gradle dependencies: 
`modules {
        module('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8') {
            replacedBy 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib', 'kotlin fixes'
        }
        module('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7') {
            replacedBy 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib', 'kotlin fixes'
        }
    }`

Comment: @ValentinCerneanu Has your issue been resolved after applying **Adam Marr**'s solution?. I am still facing same issue even after applying the solution?

Comment: @AdamMarr I am still facing the error even after applying what you suggested. Can you suggest any alternative?

Answer (score 148):

For me it was strange because I didn't even include these dependencies.
However, excluding `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` worked.
Add the following at the end of `build.gradle (:app)`

```
configurations.implementation {
exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this lifesaver for those shunning Kotlin.

Comment: Worked. I really hate to do strange things without the slightest clue as to the reason for it. I just upgraded from Gradle 7.5 to 8 and removed unused google-services.json and got this error...

Comment: worked for me also. It also shows up for me because the app wizzard now includes this dependency:

implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0'

I'm going to go bang my head against a brick wall now.

Comment: I now get errors along the lines of Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to translate mine to the Kotlin DSL: 
`configurations.implementation {
    exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
}`

Comment: This is indeed a life saver.

Comment: I also had to add the same for 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk7'

Comment: Thank you, thank you for this simple fix to the ongoing issues with jkd8. I also do not use kotlin so getting caught up in the problems (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55297/kotlin-stdlib-should-declare-constraints-on-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-and-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7) added unproductive confusion. I wasted a lot of time on the whole upgrade; now you have saved wasting more.

Comment: Remove the navigation dependancies if you are not actually using it and the error will also go away.  I accidentally used the wrong template when adding a new activity and it added all sorts of crud I didn't want.  Will teach me for being lazy instead of just adding it manually.

Comment: saved me too. as I am getting error for kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 so just replacing jdk8 to jdk7,works for me. Thanks ):

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me when upgrading the following dependency: `'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'` from `1.7.x`

Changing the kotlin plugin version in the **project-level** `build.gradle` to this fixed the issue for me.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me and seems to be a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 6):

For me worked downgrading `'androidx.core:core:1.10.0'` to `'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'`

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this same issue when trying to build a jetpack compose app. Checking the compatibility of compose compiler, compose UI version and Kotlin compiler version helped me solve this issue.
for me, the following setting worked :

```
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.2' 
compose_ui_version = '1.4.0'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
```

Note: I was just going to put it as a comment to one of the responses, but I can't :). `You must have 50 reputation to comment`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, guys!

This is the syntax that that worked for me this week.

I'll probably have to use one of the other phrasings next week, and a third one the week after.

Sometimes I think my tools are conspiring against me.

:)

```
dependencies {
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
implementation("androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6")
implementation("androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
implementation("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2")
implementation("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")
implementation("org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.23")
implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":lex")))
implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":utils")))
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.10.0")
configurations.implementation {
    exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module= "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see I was facing the same issue when I tried to use flutter's alarm package to set a notification in my app, so I added`implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))`   dependency in my app level `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, until I can fully migrate to Kotlin 1.8, I used the constraints workaround defined at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54136/Duplicated-classes-cause-build-failure-if-a-dependency-to-kotlin-stdlib-specified-in-an-android-project.

Answer (score -2):

modules {         module('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8') {             replacedBy 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib', 'kotlin fixes'         }         module('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7') {             replacedBy 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib', 'kotlin fixes'         }     }

This one given by @Adam Marr worked only.

Comment: This is not working for me. Did it work for you?