# Duplicate class error in flutter when starting app

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

When I want to start my app, I get this error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

I tried to restart my pc and flutter clean but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actual solution:**
[A failure occurred while executing app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75274720/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses/75315276#75315276)

**Possible solution 1**
Your description is insufficient for anyone to tell what might be wrong with your application, except that you might be defining an existing class name.

If you are sure you didn't override any Dart class name, and if you are using Visual Studio Code, try to delete your **".dart_tool"** folder from your project.

Then you need to run the `flutter pub get` to fix all your dependencies and rebuild the necessary folders.

**Possible solution 2**
You might have a library conflict, try to remove some of the latest packages you've added, to figure out which ones are conflicting with each other.

Comment: I commented 2 packages and the methods that used those packages but it still doesnt really work :/

Comment: I dont think that overrid any dart class name

Comment: Try if you can open a different project (it can be a new one) and try to build it.
If you still have any errors, you might have a Java JDK conflict.

Comment: I started a new app but it doesnt have errors. I'm using flutter, dart. Can a java jdk conflict really be possible?

Comment: If you have no errors with a new project, then no... You don't have any Java conflicts. The most probable cause is the libraries you are using, or your code has duplicated class names.

Comment: Check if this solves your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75315276/4605422

Comment: Now I get a new Error message xD

Comment: Now it works, thanks for the link, the new error came up because i deleted a kotlin folder from the project which included the mainactivity file

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked for me:

Look at the error message:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules 
    jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10)
 and 
    jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
```

Note that one version of the library is 1.8.10 and another one is 1.6.0.

Now go to your *android/build.gradle* file. Your `ext.kotlin_version` line in there is probably set to 1.6.0, change it to 1.8.10 (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

I think inside android/app/src/main/java there is a main file and also inside android/app/src/main/kotlin there is a main file. So the flutter framework is now confused which entry point should be used as both of them have the same name but in different language. Just remove one of the file and it shoudld work.

Or, you are using 2 versions of JDKs, just remove one of them

Comment: when i type java -version in cmd, it shows 15. dont know how to check if i use 2 versions of jdk. I deleted the kotlin file but it still doesnt work

Comment: The place where you have your JDK installed, check there once.

Comment: I deinstalled all other jdks, only jdk15 left, but still not working :/