# Create new project in Android studio, immediately get "unable to find gradle tasks to build"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I do the following:

1. Open Android studio (Flamingo, 2022.2.1 Patch 2),
2. Click on "New Project,"
3. Select "Basic Views Activity" and click "Next,"
4. Name the project, select Java as the language, and API 30, then click Finish,
5. After it loads, I get an error about resolving gradle,
6. Go to File->Settings->Build->Build Tools->Gradle and set Gradle JDK to Android Studio java home,
7. Go to the Build menu and click Make Project.

I get the error `Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:]. Build mode: ASSEMBLE. Tests: None.`

Please give step by step instructions, as I have very limited Android knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by abandoning this version of Android Studio in favor of version 2023.1.1, which quickly gave me a different error about duplicate kotlin classes, fixed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75315276/286340).

No idea why the original version wasn't working, but life is too short to root cause every bug.