# Android Studio Kotlin duplicate class build error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build-error

I have inherited a project that has compiled in the past, but after making a very small change and attempt to build results in the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':meeting:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
```

I have not attempted to build the app in a while and have updated my Android Studio environment multiple times since the last build.

I have researched this issue and found a few discussions and proposed solutions that have worked for others but do not work for me.  Other solutions include:

- [Issue building android duplicate versions of jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35979)
- [Duplicate class in Kotlin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263047/duplicate-class-in-kotlin-android)
- [Duplicated classes cause build failure if a dependency to kotlin-stdlib specified in an android project](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54136/Duplicated-classes-cause-build-failure-if-a-dependency-to-kotlin-stdlib-specified-in-an-android-project)

Follow the proposed solutions like

```
modules {
        module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7") {
            replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8") {
            replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

Gradle build throws exception:

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0, build_e4tamez9gv61axrh0xwwfc8ac$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure5$_closure6@729daddd] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyConstraintHandler
```

if I use this recommendation:

```
constraints {
        module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7") {
                replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
            module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8") {
                replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
       }
```

Gradle builds, But, I still get the the duplicate class error.

I am not ready to migrate the app to a newer version of Kotlin yet because it would require extensive refactoring.

I would like to understand this issue better but the error link is invalid:

```
Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

My current Kotlin dependency is

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

where $kotlin_version = `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.+'`

> How do I build this project without forced migration?

**My dependencies**

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

implementation(name:'amazon-chime-sdk-media', ext:'aar')


implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'
```

I stil get the error, even if I comment out:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'
```

**Full build error:**

> Task :meeting:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':meeting:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)

 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get past the issue.  The partial answer can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35979).  The missing piece was to comment out the following:

```
...
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

...

//implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.20

...
```

and add:

```
constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

I was not commenting out previously

```
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

when encountering the error.  These also need to be commented out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99 percent sure that one of the dependencies is in conflict with another. I had the same issue today and I solved it by removing some dependencies.

For example, this worked good:

```
androidx.coroutines:1.2.3 and androidx.compose.1.2.3
```

But this had an error:

```
androidx.coroutines:1.2.3 and androidx.compose.1.2.2
```

Let us know the solution

Comment: I agree that it's likely in a dependency somewhere, I will remove them one at a time and see what comes of it.  I was just wondering if there was something like the `constraints` wrapper in `build.gradle `that would work that's different from the suggestions that have not.

Comment: Please see my edit with listed dependencies.  I have tried your suggesting but still get the error.