# Why i am getting this error Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jamvm

Whenever i am setting the depedency

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
ie, these are the new version available in android studio, My build is failed. How can i use      these setting still and able to run my project
```

After changing the versions to a lower one i am only able to build it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75700273/android-studio-kotlin-duplicate-class-build-error please check this one.