# How to solve a "Duplicate class" problem in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started learning app development and Android Studio shows error. What should I do?

I cleared the caches and reloaded the project but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Please scroll through the list on the left in an upward direction and find a more accurate description of the problem there.

Comment: Did you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263047/duplicate-class-in-kotlin-android ?

Comment: My advice would be to create empty activity (when creating a new project) in that case you would start with one activity and one layout because now you have a few fragments as well which is too much if you start to learn Android.

Comment: Show your build.gradle (:app) code

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is more than one version of 'kotlin-stdlib' in your project dependencies or in some 3rd-party libraries. Clearing the cache will not help for sure.
Please check dependencies and remove kotlin-stdlib from there. It's not needed to include it manually in dependencies.

[image]