# Getting Dependency resolution errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, dependency-resolution

I am getting a dependency resolution error. i have checked many times there is no any dependency conflict. I have even trying almost all the answers from different websites on how to fix this but non of them work.

I am getting this error:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-

kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
```

App Level build.gradle file

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id("applovin-quality-service")
    }
    android {
        compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bin.file.opener.viewer"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.1.2"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "Bin File Viewer - $versionName-$versionCode")
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    namespace 'com.bin.file.opener.viewer'



    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //lotianimation
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.0.0'
    //for sdp
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'

    //    implementation project(path: ':filepicker')
        implementation 'com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:2.0.17.0'   //pdf converter
        //get hexa of file
        implementation 'at.favre.lib:bytes:1.5.0'
    //    room
        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2"
        kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2"
        androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.5.2"
    
       //applovin sdk and mediation
    //    implementation("com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.4.3")
    //    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
    //    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:facebook-adapter:6.8.0.3'
    
    //    implementation project(':adsmodule')
    
    //    constraints {
    //        implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0') {
    //            because '''androidx.work:work-runtime:2.1.0 pulled from play-services-ads
    //                   has a bug using PendingIntent without FLAG_IMMUTABLE or
    //                   FLAG_MUTABLE and will fail in apps targeting S+.'''
    //        }
    //    }
}
```

and this is my Project Gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url = uri("https://artifacts.applovin.com/android") }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21'
    classpath ("com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:4.0.0")
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can i fix this? I have even added this line in gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate class in Kotlin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263047/duplicate-class-in-kotlin-android)

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been solved Finally. After adding this dependency:

```
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```