# Build failure with Duplicate class error after partially migrating Java project to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unity-game-engine, gradle

My app has Unity embedded via Uaal. Originally it was a Java only codebase, but I wanted to start using more modern language features so I'm trying to gradually migrate parts of it to Kotlin.

To start, I used InteliJ's automated Java to Kotlin conversion on some of the files. After fixing some Kotlin syntax errors from the conversion and trying to build, I got errors like this:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class kotlin.ArrayIntrinsicsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction

Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 2 files found with path 'kotlin/annotation/annotation.kotlin_builtins' from inputs:

Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 2 files found with path 'kotlin/annotation/annotation.kotlin_builtins'.
```

```
Duplicate class kotlin.ArrayIntrinsicsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.BuilderInference found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.CharCodeJVMKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.CharCodeKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeepRecursiveFunction found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeepRecursiveKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeepRecursiveScope found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeepRecursiveScopeImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeepRecursiveScopeImpl$crossFunctionCompletion$$inlined$Continuation$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.Deprecated found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeprecatedSinceKotlin found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeprecationLevel found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.DslMarker found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExceptionsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExceptionsKt__ExceptionsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExperimentalMultiplatform found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExtensionFunctionType found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.Function found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.HashCodeKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.InitializedLazyImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.KotlinNothingValueException found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)
Duplicate class kotlin.KotlinVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib (kotlin-stdlib.jar) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22)........................
```

### What I've tried

- [Duplicate class in Kotlin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263047/duplicate-class-in-kotlin-android)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54136/Duplicated-classes-cause-build-failure-if-a-dependency-to-kotlin-stdlib-specified-in-an-android-project
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35979
  etc...

### Enviroment

- SDK Java11.0.21
- Android GradlePlugin Version 7.2.2
- Gradle Version 7.6.3
- TargetSDK 34
- min SDK 24

projectRoot

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}

ext {
    defaultTargetSdkVersion = 33
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    implementation fileTree(dir: project(':unityLibrary').getProjectDir().toString() + ('\\libs'), include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.8'
    implementation project(path: ':unityLibrary')
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-common:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
}


android {

    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.Flamers.Memoria'
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
        versionCode 20
        versionName '1.16.1'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
    namespace 'com.unity.mynativeapp'
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}
```

unitylibrary

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'bugsnag-plugin-android-anr-release', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'bugsnag-android-release', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'bugsnag-android-unity-release', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'OVRPlugin', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'tobservicelib', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'audioinaec', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'bugsnag-android-ndk-release', ext:'aar')
    implementation project('xrmanifest.androidlib')

}

android {
    ndkPath "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.10f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK"

    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdk 34
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
        versionCode 20
        versionName '1.16.0'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', '.bundle', '.unityexp'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
    }
}

def getSdkDir() {
    Properties local = new Properties()
    local.load(new FileInputStream("${rootDir}/local.properties"))
    return local.getProperty('sdk.dir')
}

def BuildIl2Cpp(String workingDir, String configuration, String architecture, String abi, String[] staticLibraries) {
    def commandLineArgs = []
    commandLineArgs.add("--compile-cpp")
    commandLineArgs.add("--platform=Android")
    commandLineArgs.add("--architecture=" + architecture)
    commandLineArgs.add("--outputpath=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.so")
    commandLineArgs.add("--baselib-directory=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniStaticLibs/" + abi)
    commandLineArgs.add("--incremental-g-c-time-slice=3")
    commandLineArgs.add("--configuration=" + configuration)
    commandLineArgs.add("--dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux")
    commandLineArgs.add("--profiler-report")
    commandLineArgs.add("--profiler-output-file=" + workingDir + "/build/il2cpp_"+ abi + "_" + configuration + "/il2cpp_conv.traceevents")
    commandLineArgs.add("--print-command-line")
    commandLineArgs.add("--data-folder=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/data")
    commandLineArgs.add("--generatedcppdir=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput")
    commandLineArgs.add("--cachedirectory=" + workingDir + "/build/il2cpp_"+ abi + "_" + configuration + "/il2cpp_cache")
    commandLineArgs.add("--tool-chain-path=" + android.ndkDirectory)
    staticLibraries.eachWithIndex {fileName, i->
        commandLineArgs.add("--additional-libraries=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniStaticLibs/" + abi + "/" + fileName)
    }
    def executableExtension = ""
    if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
        executableExtension = ".exe"
        commandLineArgs = commandLineArgs*.replace('\"', '\\\"')
    }
    exec {
        executable workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/il2cpp" + executableExtension
        args commandLineArgs
        environment "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT", getSdkDir()
    }
    delete workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.sym.so"
    ant.move(file: workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.dbg.so", tofile: workingDir + "/symbols/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.so")
}

android {
    task BuildIl2CppTask {
        doLast {
              BuildIl2Cpp(projectDir.toString().replaceAll('\\\\', '/'), 'Release', 'armv7', 'armeabi-v7a', [  ] as String[]);
              BuildIl2Cpp(projectDir.toString().replaceAll('\\\\', '/'), 'Release', 'arm64', 'arm64-v8a', [  ] as String[]);
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        if (project(':unityLibrary').tasks.findByName('mergeDebugJniLibFolders'))
            project(':unityLibrary').mergeDebugJniLibFolders.dependsOn BuildIl2CppTask
        if (project(':unityLibrary').tasks.findByName('mergeReleaseJniLibFolders'))
            project(':unityLibrary').mergeReleaseJniLibFolders.dependsOn BuildIl2CppTask
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/Il2CppOutputProject"]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help getting past this build error would be greatly appreciated!