# Duplicate Kotlin classes after installing mobilescanner

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

First ever Flutter / Android app, apologies in advance.

As soon as I install [this qr code scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner/install) it breaks my project (even if I don't actually import it).

First it complains about the compileSdkVersion and minSdkVersion. After hard coding those to 34 and 21 respectively as suggested by the error, I get a long error about duplicate Kotlin classes when I attempt to build.

The confusing thing is it worked 2 days ago, but somehow I have broken that project and any new project suffers from this problem. Perhaps the most recent update to the library could have caused this?

I've tried `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` and `./gradlew clean`, no effect. I've updated Flutter to latest version. I have created empty projects with `flutter create <name>` and done nothing but attempt to import this lib.

I understand that I must have conflicting kotlin dependencies, and presumably that means the QR scanner library has a dependency that is conflicting with my project? However I am having difficulty resolving that issue.

I am working in VSCode if that is relevant at all. Here is the full error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
```

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263047/duplicate-class-in-kotlin-android

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is with your Gradle dependencies, as you've pointed out.

It seems that while you declare `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib`, they instead declare `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`, which happen to be different packages, with the same kinds of code.  And while I can confirm that they do indeed have that dependency from [their GitHub project](https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/blob/master/android/build.gradle), I cannot really see your code!  So a bit of an assumption, here.

Anyway, a solution would be for you to drop your version of Kotlin, and piggy-back theirs.  Although, that may cause other unforeseen problems.  Alternatively, you could consider downgrading your Kotlin plugin to match theirs.

Answer (score 0):

adding this to build.gradle fixed the issue:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22'
    }
}
```

I am assuming that this is forcing the library to upgrade its kotlin dependency. Is that a dangerous move? So far, it seems to work without issue.

Comment: It'll be very hard to tell if this is a dangerous move or not.  Forcing something is usually not recommended, but the answer will lie in whether there's a difference between these libs, and how much the problematic dependency depends on these potential differences.  Def worth a deeper look before claiming this as a victory, I would say. @arcadeperfect