The Error messages from Android Studio was confusing me and no ideas how to fix it
Please help me out, that I got this special errors message when I tried to run my Project:
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

I don't know why is that happen, but I know that I download the new version of Android Studio and let new version to replace the old one. Please someone help me out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263047/duplicate-class-in-kotlin-android
